# Safe Bash Emulation - using chroot and qemu

Tags: virtualization, bash

I am trying to run a bash script in a sandbox to gain information about what it launches. There don't appear to be good emulators or static analysis tools for it, so I was going to run it in a chroot, and optionally inside a qemu-user(-static) execution of it. This allows it to have access to it's filesystem to run further, etc.

However, when I run chroot (GNU coreutils 8.25), it appears that it is perhaps detecting I'm setting my chroot into an ARM filesystem and runs as what appears to be `/usr/bin/qemu-arm /bin/sh -i`. Likewise, when my qemu-user-static spawns other things, it appears to run them on the host as `/usr/bin/qemu-arm /bin/sleep 1`.

I am having two issues:

1. I do not have a good way to identify all children it spawns so I can kill them (pgrep -P doesn't seem to identify execle branches perhaps?)
2. I am concerned that it may be not running the spawned items running in different qemu instances inside the 'host', that may not be chroot'ed.

Does anyone have recommendations for how to run this that will help ensure any things spawned during running the shell script are killed after some execution/timeout?

Comment: Do _not_ rely on chroot for security work. You want a real VM at the very minimum, and you want to significantly harden your hypervisor too. There is no safe way to do what you are trying to do.